# How can I show, that a method is synchronized in class diagram (UML)?

Tags: java, synchronization

I have created a class in java with a `public static synchronized` method.

How can I show that the public method (+) is synchronized in a class diagram?

Edit:
I want to show this in the class diagram, that is important! No need for activity diagram, only CLASS diagram...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML cannot handle synchronized by default, however, you can use stereotypes, this best described in this [Visualizing the synchronization of Java-threads with UML](https://www.academia.edu/481442/Visualizing_the_synchronization_of_Java-threads_with_UML)  paper with examples.

You may not be able to do this with class diagrams, but, you can do it with sequence diagrams.

[image]

Comment: I get the idea for activity diagrams, but does it work for class diagrams too?

Comment: For my best knowledge, No. the class diagram only address classes, their attributes and relationships between them.

Comment: Okay, well then I will explain the USAGE of the class with a sequence diagram! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a user-defined notation with adding a note.
[Note for synchronized methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4zEO.png)
[Example for synchronzed method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJTwk.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).